# winAPI c++ disable wireless adaptor

Tags: c++, winapi, wifi, adapter

I have been using the Native Wi-Fi WinAPI documentation but I still do see it really clear.

I want to turn off the wireless adaptor and the bluetooth adaptor of my computer by using the WinAPI in C++. I am almost sure I have to use the function `WlanSetInterface` from the mentioned library, but I cannot make it work. I don't know how to call the function properly.

Has anybody done this same task before so I can get some help?

Answer (score 2):

It is not quite clear what do you mean by "turn off the wireless adaptor", but as far as I know, SetupDiChangeState API can be used to enable/disable a device.

Comment: With turn off wifi adaptor I mean switch off the wifi connectivity from my computer, same as if I switched off the physical button on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Check out SetupApi this api allows you to tamper with the hardware devices.You can't do it using wifi api or bluetooth.